# How to make VSCode ignore a specific error

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, vendor-prefix

I wrote this CSS code in VSCode :

```
input[type="number"] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

and I get this error:

> Also define the standard property 'appearance' for compatibilitycss(vendorPrefix) ️ Property is nonstandard. Avoid using it.

How do I force VSCode to ignore this error ?

just ignoring this error and removing the red line below it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add standard property **appearance** with same value with **-moz-appearance** to remove the error.
In your case:

```
input[type='number'] {
  appearance: textfied;
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

Comment: please try to avoid answering duplicate questions. see [answer]. also, this doesn't actually answer the question.